# How to center the contents of first-row and first-col?

Tags: math-mode, nicematrix

I got a custom code to typset nodes documentation for matrices. Such documentation is outside the brackets of a matrix

[image]

The result is as desired, but I want to see if it is possible to place the contents of first-row and first-col to the center of their columns, while also maintain `r` column specification for the matrix itself. Also, is it possible to set `cell-space-limits` but also avoid adding the the space below `first-col`?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\compel}[1]{
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[rectangle, draw, minimum height=3ex, minimum width=3ex, rounded corners=1.5ex] (char) {#1};
    }
}
\newcommand{\nodesymbol}[1]{\compel{#1}}

\usepackage{nicematrix} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceArray}{r r r r}[cell-space-limits=6pt, first-row, first-col]
        
        & \nodesymbol{A} & \nodesymbol{B} & \nodesymbol{C} & \nodesymbol{D}
        \\
        
        \nodesymbol{A} & 1.15 & 321 & 572 & 214
        \\
        
        \nodesymbol{B} & 574 & 710 & 230 & 130
        \\
        
        \nodesymbol{C} & 790 & 211 & 570 & 325
        \\
        
        \nodesymbol{D} & 621 & 240 & 390 & 170
        \\
        
    \end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have your tied `c` instead of `r` at the column declaration of `bNiceArray`? See the `nicematrix` manual for more information and several examples using different column types?

Comment: @cabohah. I edited the qeustion

Comment: Have you read section 4 of the `nicematrix` manual, that explains how to use, e.g. `\Block[C]{1-1}{…}`?

Comment: Yes, but I am asking whether it is possible to add this as option for all contents of `first-row` and `first-col` as an option

Comment: Why do you insist in using an option. You are already using a macro `\nodesymbol` in the first row and the first column. So it should be easy to extend this by a block command or replace it with a new defined command `\newcommand{\firstrowcolumnsymbol}[1]{\Block[C]{1-1}{\compel{#1}}}` or something similar.

Comment: Good comment. May you convert it to an answer?